# Using pushState to change urls. How do I navigate to the exact placement directly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using replaceState (pushState) to change the url as the user scrolls the website. 
It is working as expected, and the url is changed. However, if I copy the generated url lets say

```
example.com/vision
```

open a new tab and navigate to this, I will get a 404 not found page.
I know that if I use anchor links in the url such as

```
example.com/#vision
```

it works, but I dont want the `#`.

How can I overcome this, and navigate the visitor to the exact place in the webpage instead of 404?

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView("#1")) { window.history.replaceState("state", "title", "home"); return; }
    if (isScrolledIntoView("#2")) { window.history.replaceState("state", "title", "profile"); return; }
    if (isScrolledIntoView("#3")) { window.history.replaceState("state", "title", "vision"); return; }
    if (isScrolledIntoView("#4")) { window.history.replaceState("state", "title", "contacts"); return; }
});
```

Comment: Despite changing the URL with pushstate, it still needs to exist when a request is made to it. This is the main reason people use `#` when dealing with pushState; it means you don't need to deal with problems like this as you only need a single page to deal with all the requests. For it to work in the manner you want you will need to use server-side routing as well as the pushState logic, but then you're getting in to validating that the routes exist from the client - which will be a mess. The short and simple answer here is to just use `#`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi and thank you for your comment. Does the server-side routing is in the terms of rewrite rules such as `RewriteRule ^articles/?$ articles/index.php [NC,L]` ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP with that level, but it would seem as though that's the right path, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something you can do client-side. In order for your urls to work and not throw a 404 error, you'll have to rewrite them to the page using `htaccess`. One option would be to pass the page as a parameter and use it to scroll to the appropriate position using `JavaScript`.

**Htaccess:**

```
RewriteRule ^(home|profile|vision|contacts)/?$ /index.php?hash=$1 [NC,L]
```

**PHP:**

```php
<script = "application/javascript">
   var hash = "<?= $_GET['hash'] ?? ""; ?>";
</script>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
$(function () {
   if (hash) {
      $("html, body").animate({
         scrollTop: $("#" + hash).offset().top
      }, "slow");
   }
});
```

Then your code should work normally.

Comment: γεια σου φίλε, σε ευχαριστώ για την απάντηση. So, what I did, I used the codes above into the website. The one in the htaccess file, and the other into the file and above the code I added in my question. Now, there are no 404 errors, but when I open the page like example.com/profile it does not navigate to the specific anchor...

Comment: I found it, thank you, it works. Αν σε ενδιαφέρει να εργαστείς σε projects ενημέρωσε με. Έχουμε startups σε Ελλάδα και Κύπρο με επενδυτές.

Comment: You're welcome @EnexoOnoma. I'm glad I could help  *(Σαν προοπτική σίγουρα θα με ενδιέφερε, ωστόσο, εξαρτάται και από το/τα πρότζεκτ. Επισκέφτηκα το προφίλ σου αλλά δεν έχεις δηλώσει κάποια μέθοδο επικοινωνίας, οπότε σου αφήνω το [email μου](https://3q3.de/ma32yolni8 "Προστατευμένο από μελλοντικούς spammers") για να επικοινωνήσεις εσύ)*.

Comment: σου έχω απαντήσει μόλις τώρα στο mail